# My keyboard on MacBook got stuck - do Apple Stores fix it without Apple Care?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair, apple-store

The delete key on my MacBook (mid-2017 12' model) seems to have got stuck and often it won't respond to my pushing on the key.

So I temporarily swapped the delete key for the backslash but I rather want to fix it. But I find it is incredibly hard to fix it on my own, so I consider bringing it to the Apple Store.

But my MacBook is neither covered by the Apple Care program nor was purchased in a country where I'm in now. Is it possible to fix it up at the Apple Store and does the fix of the stuck keyboard get me charged (if so, approximately how much)?

Comment: Alternatively, you could take the laptop to a licensed repairman for a whole lot less money.

Comment: @E.Huckabee Make sure it is Apple certified.

Comment: Agreed with JBis. I should have clarified better. An Apple licensed repair service could repair the key, or replace the keyboard if necessary. They have access to the parts and have the know-how to fix your keyboard. Another thing I would suggest is taking some form of pressurized air and blast out your keyboard. The butterfly MK. 2 in the 2016 MBPs tend to get stuck when dust gets underneath the keys. Doing this might save you some money. (you could also just use your mouth. Ive done this, I don't like doing it, but I've done it.)

Comment: Also, if the key has broken within the first year of you purchasing the laptop (I.E. you just recently purchased it since July of last year) Then your computer is covered by 1 year of free Apple Care and Apple can repair your computer for free.

Comment: You never mentioned which MacBook you have.  Some like the MacBook Pros, like 2012 and earlier can have the keyboard replaced while newer ones require the entire top case to be replaced.

Comment: @Allan I think after the release of the ultralight 12' model the "MacBook" only refers to it... But I edited it anyway for clarification.

Comment: That model uses the new "butterfly key" that has been notorious for issues..  It needs to be replaced.

Comment: It does not matter which country are you in. I have repaired my laptop in countries other than purchased under Apple repair program.Just take to Apple Store to replace it for free. Check "Keyboard Service Program for MacBook and MacBook Pro - Apple"

https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you live. Apple Care covers your computer no matter what. If you just recently bought the computer in-between July 8th of this year and last year then you can get the key repaired for free.

If not, then try to find a repair service near you via [this link](https://locate.apple.com). Apple has licensed resellers all over the world and most of them also do repairs. If your computer is badly damaged, they are going to send it in to get it repaired and you may end up paying a whole lot of money and you won't have your laptop for several weeks.

Alternatively, you could try to fix it yourself. This is highly risky if you don't know what your doing and you could end up permanently damaging the computer. I don't know what model your laptop is, but if it is 2016 or newer, it has the butterfly 2 mechanism in the keyboard. I know from personal experience that this style of keyboard tends to get stuck really easily when dust and grit get underneath the keys. I just blow it out and that has worked every time.

If your laptop is 2015 or older, you have the butterfly 1 mechanism. If your key is stuck it could be legitimately damaged. I would recommend at least trying to blow it out with some high-powered air. If that doesn't work you will need to take it to someone to get repaired.

Comment: Thanks and how did you blow it to get it working again? It is your mouse or something others?

Comment: My option key on the left side had the same problem your key had. I followed [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnroNe9NduU) to fix it. The tutorial worked and I didn't have to get it repaired. Remember to be extremely careful when attempting self repairs.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the Apple Store and got my MacBook repaired. The staff checked the key and found that the inside of the key was cracked, and also the wire that fixed the key was crooked. He replaced it with a new key, and then blowed all the other keys as well as wiping them off. It was free of charge, but took 4 hours to get repaired...

They did not ask where I purchased it, FIY.